# TableRow increseas when it has a button in it

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following basic XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TableRow
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:layout_weight="0.8">
    <TextView
        android:text="Bottom menu" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:background="#0000FF"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">
    <Button
       android:text="Prev"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</TableRow>
```

The height of the TableRow on the emulator is about 3cm, if I change the Button to a TextView, it would be 2.5cm. Can someone explain why the TableRow automatically increases in size?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have set the layout_height to "wrap_content" would be my guess (you really shouldn't strip out things when asking for help troubleshooting).

It resizes itself to fit around what it contained, and a button has padding that a textview does.not.